# Sidebar "Item" Tab has Disappeared

Tags: interface, panel

I've been using Blender for a couple of weeks now, and things have been going well until today when the "Item" tab in the sidebar suddenly wasn't there any longer. (See screenshot)

I've looked through the manual to see if there's an option and keymaps for hiding and showing sidebar tabs that I might have triggered by accident but I wasn't able to find anything like that. Nothing useful came up from a general Google search either.

Any advice or assistance would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello. By default this panel only appears when you have an object selected in the viewport. Otherwise, try disabling your addons one by one and see if it reappears when one of your addons is disabled.

Comment: To be more precise, as @Gorgious said it is there when you have selected an object in the viewport. Although, after you've deselected all objects the _Item_ tab usually stays there, as does the origin of the last selected object and the _Properties Editor_ still shows its properties. However if you delete the selected object then there is no more origin or properties to be shown since the object does not exist anymore. In this case the _Item_ tab is hidden until you select another object.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I _was_ seeing this issue when an object was selected, but only immediately after opening a file, so you can understand my confusion. Now I know I have to unselect whatever is selected when a file is opened.